# Client-side JS takes longer for server requests

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest

I am populating data on a page after a user logs in.  Without any client-side JS, this happens instantly since the server is sending data back with the response.  The corresponding HTML is just a simple handlebars file.

Server-side index.js:

```
/* GET root page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return res.redirect('/home');
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
});

// GET home page.
router.get('/home', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ gender: 'female'}, (err, all) => {
    res.render('home', {
      all: all
    })
  })
})
```

When using client-side JS, it takes longer to load the data (about a fraction of a second).  I think it's because the client must make another trip to the server after the page is rendered.

Client-side `home.js`:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      if (window.location.pathname === '/home') {
        document.getElementById('all-members').innerHTML = output;
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', '/home_test', true)
  xhr.send()
})
```

Server-side index.js:

```
/* GET root page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return res.redirect('/home');
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
});

router.get('/home_test', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ gender: 'female'}, (err, all) => {
    res.send(all)
  })
})

// GET home page.
router.get('/home', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ gender: 'female'}, (err, all) => {
    res.render('home', {
      all: all
    })
  })
})
```

The corresponding html file is just `<div id="all-members"></div>`.

Can I mimic the server side response (where the data is loaded instantly in the client) using client-side JS?